# Remove tags from parent but not from child

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom-manipulation

I want to remove `<br>` tags and `&nbsp;` tags from `<div>` but not from child `span` class code

Here is my dom looks like

```
<div>
 some &nbsp; text
 <br>
 some &nbsp;text
 <br>
 some &nbsp; text

 <span class='code'>//Code
  <pre>
   <p>
    &nbsp;text here 
    <br>
    &nbsp;text here 
    <br>
    &nbsp;text here 
    <br>
   </p>
  </pre>
 </span>

</div>
```

How to do this is jquery or javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
var divhtml = $('.code').parent().html().replace(/<br>/g,'').replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
$('.code').parent().html(divhtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get the code span
var codeSpan = document.querySelector("span.code");

// Remove the codeSpan from the DOM
codeSpan.remove();

// Get the div
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var html = div.innerHTML;

// Remove all the <br> and &nbsp; from the div
div.innerHTML = html.replace(/<br>/g,'').replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');

// ---- Alternate approach
// Clear out all the content from the div
// div.innerHTML = "";

// Add the codeSpan back into the div
div.appendChild(codeSpan);
```

```html
<div>
 some &nbsp; text
 <br>
 some &nbsp;text
 <br>
 some &nbsp; text

 <span class='code'>//Code
  <pre>
   <p>
    &nbsp;text here 
    <br>
    &nbsp;text here 
    <br>
    &nbsp;text here 
    <br>
   </p>
  </pre>
 </span>

</div>
```